# Is there a way to assign to several variables at once with the apply function?

Tags: r

I want to loop over a list and based on that list assign to two separate variables in the same iteration.

I know how to do this with for loops, but as I've understood it for loops are slow and best to be avoided in R. So I wonder how to instead do this with the apply or lapply function (whichever one would work best).

With a for loop, I would solve the issue like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(li)) {
  if (li[[i]]$foo < best_foo) {
    best_foo <- li[[i]]$foo
    best_i <- i
  }
}
```

How can I do this with the apply function? Is it even possible?

Comment: This could probably be expressed with something like `foos  <- sapply(li, \(x) x$foo)` followed by `best_foo <- min(foos)` and `best_i <- which.min(foos)`. It would be good to provide a bit more context about what you're doing, i.e. what the data contained in the list is and what you expect the output to be. See [How to write a good R question with a reproducible example](How to write a good R question with a reproducible example).

Comment: Totally agreed that `for` loops are best avoided, but (at least in the case you’ve shown) the reason isn’t their performance (speed isn’t an issue here) but rather that they’re more code and harder to read. But `lapply()` (at least by itself) isn’t the right function here: its meaning is, quite literally: “transform every input item using some function”. This isn’t what you’re doing here.

Comment: Sorry my link didn't work - I meant [How to write a good R question with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lapply()` to extract the `foo` values, and then find the maximum of those:

```
foos <- unlist(lapply(li, `[[`, 'foo'))
best_i <- which.max(foos)
best_foo <- foos[[best_i]]
```

Comment: The logic in the loop in the question implies that each `li[[i]]$foo` is atomic, so `sapply(...)` rather than `unlist(lapply(...))` might be more concise here.

Comment: @AllanCameron `sapply()` is error-prone and therefore essentially has *no place* in reusable scripts. I would always flag it in code reviews. If you don’t want the unnecessary `unlist(lapply())`, you could instead use `vapply()` (which I would generally use if the data type is known and informative, but is even less concise), or a strongly-typed wrapper (e.g. from ‘purrr’, or self-written — personally [I tend to use the latter](https://github.com/klmr/box/blob/2cef22e63abeedefa82e45b12f3f584301988733/R/map.r)). But fingers off `sapply()`, please.

Comment: I think that's a good argument for not using `sapply` without knowing the caveats (most of which are caused by the default processing by `simplify2array`). I certainly use `vapply` more often in production code, but if used in a code path with upstream type and length checking I think an absolute prohibition on `sapply` is overkill where it improves code readability. I fear not for my fingers on the odd time they reach for sapply.

Comment: @AllanCameron The issue with that approach is that it leads to a *much* more complex rule for when to use `sapply()` (instead of the trivial rule “never”), which increases cognitive load. I’m not even against using it categorically but I have a hard time imagining a situation that would tip the balance in its favour (short of always specifying `simplify = FALSE`, and then its advantage is gone). In fact, I used to use it exactly as you described, but found it a drastic improvement to just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(mtcars[1:3,], 2,function (x,aa,bb) {
    x["added"]<-aa
    x[bb]<-aa+x["carb"]
    x
},5,"bla ")
```

- `mtcars[1:3,]`: only 3 first line for have an example
- 1: MARGIN. In the doc of `apply()`:`for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns,`
- `function (x,aa,bb) {}` anonym function called by `apply()`
- `,5,"bla ")` : parameter `aa` and `bb` for the anonym function
- `x["added"]<-aa`: create a new variable `added` set with param `aa`
- `x[bb]<-aa+x["carb"]`: create a new variable named by `bb` param set with param `aa` + mtcars `carb` column
- `x` ie `return(x)` ie return `x` updated

```
mpg       21.00        21.000      22.80
cyl        6.00         6.000       4.00
disp     160.00       160.000     108.00
hp       110.00       110.000      93.00
drat       3.90         3.900       3.85
wt         2.62         2.875       2.32
qsec      16.46        17.020      18.61
vs         0.00         0.000       1.00
am         1.00         1.000       1.00
gear       4.00         4.000       4.00
carb       4.00         4.000       1.00
added      5.00         5.000       5.00
bla        9.00         9.000       6.00
```